# Cannot create bootable Windows 10 pendrive

Tags: boot, partitioning, usb-drive

I need to install Windows 10 on another machine. I want to use my Ubuntu 16.04 to create bootable pendrive. I downloaded iso image from Microsoft site, used `Disks` utility and option `Restore Partition Image...`.
Configuration now looks like on the screen below, but the computer is not booting from this pendrive. When I select to boot from pendrive I can see only black screen and nothing happens for a long time. I tried to change partition type, but it still cannot boot.
Any advice?

[image]

Comment: Newer Windows 10 ISOs do not support that method. You can use MKUSB and while at that read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive

Comment: @karel I know but though it would be best to 1. explain with the OP's method no longer works and 2. present a viable alternative where so many other tools now fail. PS - I flagged the same dupe, in case you haven't noticed.

Comment: @user692175 ^^^^^ mkusb instructions for making a Windows 10 bootable USB are at the same link mentioned above at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu/837380#837380